# Initial value for variables

Tags: z3, z3py

I would like to set the initial value for variables in z3py in an efficient way.

```py
x,y = Ints(x,y)
s = Solver()
s.add(x>10)
s.check()
s.model()
```

I would expect the output value is e.g., x = 11, y = 0, not the result x = 11, y = 7.

One way to do it is:

```py
x,y = Ints(x,y)
s = Optimize()
s.add_soft(x==0)
s.add_soft(y==0)
s.add(x>10)
s.check()
s.model()
```

But it takes much computation time as my program contains many of variables. Any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The slow-down is because you're forcing the optimizer to run, which is an overkill for this purpose. (The optimizing solver can handle max-sat problems, which does the job here, but it is costly and not needed for this case.)

Instead, simply walk over the model and see if there's an assignment for it:

```py
from z3 import *

def model_with_zeros(s, vs):
    m = s.model()

    result = []
    for v in vs:
        val = m.eval(v)
        if val.eq(v):
            result.append((v, 0))
        else:
            result.append((v, val))

    return result


x, y = Ints('x y')
s = Solver()
s.add(x > 10)

print s.check()
print model_with_zeros(s, [x, y])
```

This prints:

```
sat
[(x, 11), (y, 0)]
```

Note that you have to explicitly pass the solver and the variables you are interested in to the `model_with_zeros` function; as the trick here is precisely to see which variables the solver left untouched.

If you want a different initial value, then you can modify `model_with_zeros` to account for that for each variable separately.